# javascript document onmousedown cancels element onclick

Tags: javascript, click, conflict, mousedown

I have `document.addEventListener('mousedown', ...)` performing some visual feedback to the user. But I also have dynamicaly created elements with `elem.addEventListener('click')` which are not fired. If I remove document mousedown listener then clicks on elements are triggered (or if I change document's mousedown to click event). Why is that and how to solve this? I would realy need document to handle mousedown and still be able for elements to recieve their click/tap events.

FIDDLE: http://codepen.io/hpet/pen/izpJK
if you uncomment document mousedown event, element receives click ok, otherwise click on element is never triggered.

Fiddle updated. Uncomment lines 22/23 (setting position) will not fire click event.

Comment: Did you check this behavior in all the browsers? Could you provide us a JsFiddle/SO's own snippet? Will help us understand your code

Comment: I have just tried in chrome as this is targeted engine. Will prepare fiddle...

Comment: I added link to the fiddle in my original post

Comment: fiddling around I noticed this strange behavior: if I comment el.style.left/right on mousedown event, then everything works!?

Comment: @hpet, you are moving your circle element on top of the square element. Therefore, when `mousedown` returns, the mouse pointer is considered to be above the circle, not the square, and the `click` event on the square is not triggered.

Comment: @Frederic hm... if I understand you correct I have kind of z-index issue? any solution to that?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't think that is the case, because I tried the user's code and removed the "tap" div . It still behaves the same: http://jsfiddle.net/2eqzdb31/1/

Comment: @LearningNeverStops I checked your fiddle and I think "alert" you used conflicts with mouseup (alert steals mouseup position). I think Frederic is on the spot.

Comment: @hpet Yes indeed you are correct. My mistake :|

Comment: @hpet, yes, applying a greater z-index to the `#mybox` element than to the `tap` element fixes the problem in my tests.

Comment: @Frederic this works, but then "tap" feedback is not top-most anymore. It will appear behind box. Any idea how to keep it top-most and still propagate event to the box?

Comment: @hpet, you probably can use [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) if the browsers you target support that feature.

Comment: Yej!, pointer-events appears to be a solution to this problem. Thanks to all for help and Frederic to point out problem and solution.

Comment: @Frédéric please post as answer so I can accept your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is overlapping elements.

Since you're moving the circle element on top of the square element in your `mousedown` handler, the subsequent `mouseup` event will be triggered on the circle. Since that event was not triggered on the square element, no `click` event will be generated.

If you have to keep the circle element on top of the square, you can use the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS rule to force mouse events to "go through" the circle element.